# Make AsyncAppData in Kinvey serial

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kinvey

I want to get a data from a kinvey Collection, put it in a db and then modify it locally.I want to be sure that all data is gotten from collection  before any modification. My problem is that, getting collection is done via AsyncAppData which runs in background,which makes my task impossible.

A sample code is shown

```
//getting data
ArrayList<String> runfunc = new ArrayList<String>();       
final AsyncAppData<EventEntityWhy> myevents4 = mKinveyClient.appData("WhyWorldTemp", EventEntityWhy.class);
    myevents4.get(new KinveyListCallback<EventEntityWhy>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(EventEntityWhy[]){
            for (EventEntityWhy x1 : result) {
                String temp1 = (String) x1.get("whyindex");
                runfunc.add(temp1)
            }
        }
      }
//then processing will start
//runfunc array will be processed here
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how asynchronous programming works, and Kinvey has no plans to change that paradigm. The proper way to build your code is by processing your data inside the onSuccess callback rather than on the mainthread.

What you could do is set an event flag inside the callback, and then you create a waiter at your "//then processing will start" point that waits for that flag.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Would you please explain in more detail how to implement your second paragraph.

Comment: my specialty is Kinvey, but unfortunately not Java programming, so I'll let somebody else provide a best practice there.